# Connecting to Oracle database with gorm in golang

Tags: oracle, go, orm, go-gorm

Previously i was using `godror` package to connect to oracle database client. And now i want to implement **ORM** in my system and want to connect to oracle using GORM package but it seems i am unable to do it though.
I did found out a package https://github.com/CengSin/oracle but the package installation seem to fail. Trying:
`go get github.com/cengsin/oracle`

I seem to be stuck on this.

Comment: Can you add the error log please?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

So, it seems that while installing package `go get github.com/cengsin/oracle` , gorm package needed to be of version less than or equal to v1.20.1. I downgraded my gorm package to version 1.20.1 and it solved my issue.